# Can you use the treadmill with APT?

Tags: treadmill, hip, glutes

Male, 16, 167 lbs. If I have anterior pelvic tilt, can I use the treadmill or will it worsen my situation? I’m trying to activate my glutes and hips (I can feel glutes, but can’t feel my hip at all), but my hamstrings keep tighteting intensely  instead in any exercise I try. I heard that mindfulness will help, and that it will work when I lose weight (my thighs and butt are way too fat), and I want to use the treadmill. Will it worsen my APT? Is there any other way? I have a sedentary lifestyle if that helps, too

Answer (score 0):

That highly depends how you use treadmill. Are you walking or running. If running - heel-toes, or whole foot? Mindfulness can help, in the way that you are more aware what is going on with your body.

When standing - squeeze gluts and watch how that changing other parts. Hips are moved to better position, knees goes outside (a bit but still), and you are standing more on outer part of feet. That is because gluts are not only straighten femur-pelvis joint, but also rotates out femur. When walking try to keep that patterns - walk on outer part of feet, keep knees a bit out and use gluts to control hips.

Treadmill means running. Besides what I've wrote above. Land on mid-feet, not on hills. Rather outer part, and then use big toe to bounce. That make you landing on front foot when it is quite close to your body. Which is good. Your knees will be happy.